# Using Excel Match function in Word VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I had a Word VBA macro that worked perfectly to populate data from an Excel workbook (which is acting as the 'database'). It called the excel Index and Match functions.  However, as of today, I repeatedly get an error telling me that the Match and Index functions could not be found.  What happened?  Code is below.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
    bStart = True
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Set xldocbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("D:/Dr list.xlsx")
Set xldocsheet = xldocbook.Worksheets(1)

'Set the current selection
With xlapp.WorksheetFunction

    IUH = .Index(xldocsheet.Range("I:I"), .Match(DrName, xldocsheet.Range("E:E"), 0))

    If IUH = "N" Then
        Address = .Index(xldocsheet.Range("K:K"), .Match(DrName, xldocsheet.Range("E:E"), 0))
        CityStateZip = .Index(xldocsheet.Range("L:L"), .Match(DrName, xldocsheet.Range("E:E"), 0))
    Else
        Address = ""
        CityStateZip = ""
    End If

    Phone = .Index(xldocsheet.Range("F:F"), .Match(DrName, xldocsheet.Range("E:E"), 0))

    Fax = .Index(xldocsheet.Range("G:G"), .Match(DrName, xldocsheet.Range("E:E"), 0))

    FullAddress = Address + " " + CityStateZip

    Debug.Print "Full Address is" + FullAddress

End With

xldocbook.Close

If bStart = True Then
    xlapp.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Anything change on the computer? Did you upgrade office (shouldn't have had an effect). Did you remove excel? It looks fine to me

Comment: What is the exact text of the error you're seeing?  Is it possible you're just not getting a match on your search term?

Answer (score 0):

replacing Worksheetfunction with application might be useful

Comment: This might be considered a useful answer. Might not be. Consider using a few more words, ideally to phrase an explanation. Add some punctuation if you are feeling specially generous.